# How to open an R data file in R window

Tags: r

I have some data in R that I intend to analyze. However, the file is not displaying the data. Instead, It is only showing a variable in the data. The following is the procedure I used to load the data and the output produced.

```
load("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1_29_923-Macdonell.RData")

data=load("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1_29_923-Macdonell.RData")

data
```

[1] "HeightFinger"

How do I get to view the data?

Comment: change your back slashes to forward slashes (\ to /) or replace \ with \\

Comment: or change them to double-backslashes ... what happened when you tried the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [read `?help`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html), it says that the return value of `load` is:

> A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.

This suggests (but admittedly does not state) that the true work of the `load` command is by [*side-effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), in that it inserts the objects into an environment (defaulting to the current environment, often but not always `.GlobalEnv`). You should immediately have access to them from where you called `load(...)`.

For instance, if I can guess at variables you might have in your `rda` file:

```
x
# Error: object 'x' not found

# either one of these on windows, NOT BOTH
dat = load("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1_29_923-Macdonell.RData")
dat = load("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/1_29_923-Macdonell.RData")

dat
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
x
# [1] 42
```

If you want them to be *not* stored in the current environment, you can set up an environment to place them in. (I use `parent=emptyenv()`, but that's not strictly required. There are some minor ramifications to not including that option, none of them earth-shattering.)

```
myenv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
dat = load("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/1_29_923-Macdonell.RData",
           envir = myenv)
dat
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
ls(envir = myenv)
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

From here you can get at your data in any number of ways:

```
ls.str(myenv) # similar in concept to str() but for environments
# x :  num 42
# y :  num 1
# z :  num 2
myenv$x
# [1] 42
get("x", envir = myenv)
# [1] 42
```

**Side note:**

You may have noticed that I used `dat` as my variable name instead of `data`. Though you are certainly allowed to use that, it can bite you if you use variable names that match existing variables or functions. For instance, all of your code will work just fine as long as you load your data. If, however, you run some of your code *without* pre-loading your objects into your `data` variable, you'll likely get an error such as:

```
mean(data$x)
# Error in data$x : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

That error message is not immediately self-evident. The problem is that if not previously defined as in your question, then `data` here refers to the ***function*** [`data`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html). In programming terms, a [closure is a special type of function](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), so the error really should have said:

```
# Error in data$x : object of type 'function' is not subsettable
```

meaning that though `dat` can be subsetted and `dat$x` means something, you cannot use the `$` subset method on a function itself. (You can't do `mean$x` when referring to the `mean` function, for example.) Regardless, even though this here-modified error message is less confusing, it is still not clearly telling you what/where the problem is located.

Because of this, many seasoned programmers will suggest you use unique variable names (perhaps more than just `x` :-). If you use my suggestion and name it `dat` instead, then the mistake of not preloading your data will instead error with:

```
mean(dat$x)
# Error in mean(dat$x) : object 'dat' not found
```

which is a lot more meaningful and easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to save R objects, and you've got them mixed up. In the first way, you `save()` any collection of objects **in an environment** to a file. When you `load()` that file, those objects are re-created **with their original names** in your current environment. This is how R saves and resotres workspaces.

The second way stores (serializes) a single R object into a file with the `saveRDS()` function, and recreates it in your environment with the `readRDS()` function. If you **don't** assign the results of `readRDS()`, it'll just print to your screen and drift away.

Examples below:

```
# Make a simple dataframe
testdf <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                     y = rnorm(10))

# Save it out using the save() function
savedir <- tempdir()
savepath <- file.path(savedir, "saved.Rdata")
save(testdf, file = savepath)

# Delete it
rm(testdf)

# Load without assigning - and it's back in your environment
load(savepath)
testdf

# But if you assign the results of load, you just get the name of the object
wrong <- load(savepath)
wrong


# Compare with the RDS:
rds_path <- file.path(savedir, "testdf.rds")
saveRDS(testdf, file = rds_path)
rm(testdf)
testdf <- readRDS(file = rds_path)
testdf
```

Why the two different approaches? The `save()`-environment approach is good for creating a checkpoint of your entire environment that you can restore later - that's what R uses it for - but that's about it. It's too easy for such an environment to get cluttered, and if an object you `load()` has the same name as an object in your current environment, **it will overwrite that object**:

```
testdf$z <- "blah"
load(savepath)
testdf  # testdf$z is gone
```

The RDS method lets you assign the name on read, as you're looking to do here. It's a little more annoying to save multiple objects, sure, but you probably shouldn't be saving objects very often anyway - recreating objects from scratch is the best way to ensure that your R code does what you think it does.

Comment: Nice, our answers aren't completely redundant, there's some good complement to them.

Comment: I think your bolded comment of overwriting the object cannot be overstated. More the point is that it overwrites it silently with no indication, message, or warning. The only inkling the user will have to it having been done is that future calculations may not match previous results. (I speak from painful experience ...)

Comment: @r2evans Same here. :(