# Can I pass row elements as arguments with apply? How?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing, apply, mle

Starting with some sample data:

```
sample_data <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                          x = c(128, 113, 126), 
                          n = c(347, 344, 347), 
                          m = c(335, 334, 347), 
                          index = c(11, 9, -1))

theta <- matrix(c(0.5 ,0.5, 2, 2), nrow=2, ncol=2)

lhs <- function(a, b, g, d, dat){

    beta(a + dat$x, b + dat$n - dat$x) / beta(a, b) * beta(g, d + dat$n) / beta(g, d)
}
```

The function lhs returns a vector of the same number of rows as the argument dat.

```
rhs <- function(dat, ...){

  n = dat$n
  m = dat$m
  x = dat$x
  index = dat$x

  temp <- data.frame(i = 0:index, 
                 n = rep(n, index + 1) , 
                 m = rep(m, index + 1) , 
                 x = rep(x, index + 1))

  sum(beta(a + temp$x, b + temp$m - temp$x + temp$i) / beta(a,b) * beta(g + 1, d + temp$m + temp$i) / beta(g, d))

}
```

The function rhs works only on a single row because each observation has a different value for index (the index for the sum inside rhs).  The intent is to return one value per row in dat.  I've tried to do this with apply in the function LL (below).

```
LL <- function(theta, dat){
  a <- theta[1,1]
  b <- theta[2,1]
  g <- theta[1,2]
  d <- theta[2,2]

  .lhs <- lhs(a, b, g, d, dat)

  .rhs <- ifelse(index > -1, apply(dat, 1, rhs), 0)

  sum(log(.lhs+log.rhs))
 }
```

It seems like I need to be able to pass the value of index, n, m, and x to rhs from a given row.  That is, not a vector of length(data$n), but the value of n at that row being passed through apply in the function LL.

Is this the correct approach?  How can I do such a thing?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I've clean things up a bit and made a slight modification to the sample data. The correct return value -I think! - can be arrived at by (explicitly passing a,b,g, and d)

```
sum(lhs(a = theta[1,1], 
        b = theta[2,1],
        g = theta[1,2],
        d = theta[2,2],
        sample_data)) +
 rhs(sample_data[1,]) +
 rhs(sample_data[2,]) +
 rhs(sample_data[3,])
```

Comment: Perhaps `mapply` can work for you here. What is your intended output given your `data` example? (BTW: I strongly suggest *not* using `data` as a variable name ... see the "Side Note" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43398262/3358272).)

Comment: Would a formulation of the form: `sapply(1:nrow(data),function(i) rhs(index = i,x= data$x[i],...))` work for you? It is a way to cheat a loop into an apply function when you need the index.

Comment: Don't add "solutions" to your question. If you think you've found an answer to your question, post it below as an answer. That will allow the community to vote which is how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.

Comment: @r2evans - I've added what I think is the correct return value as an edit.

Comment: @Bishops_Guest - Is the suggestion to replace apply with sapply, or to use sapply to get the index that I want and pass that as an argument?

Comment: @MrFlick - That isn't the programmatic solution but the mathematical one.

Comment: All I see is a suggested solution (which @MrFlick commented on).  What I mean: you provided a 3-row input data.frame, I'm suggesting providing a *literal data.frame* that is structured correctly and, if at all possible, contains the correct values given your input and intended calculations.

Comment: lhs() returns the correctly structure data.  rhs() does not, but that is the nature of the problem.  I can restructure the return value above into a data frame but that seems a bit pedantic.  If I could do what you're asking programmatically that would be the solution to the problem, no?